# Mysql subquery in from clause give syntax errors

Tags: mysql

I've a db where I store the answers given by users (table 'risposta_utente') to questions belonging to different lessons (table 'lezioni').
I want to get the lesson with the maximum average of the votes obtained by an user answering its questions.

ID_corso_sede_utente uniquely identify an user following the lessons of one course (because there are more then one course).

```
SELECT titolo, MAX(voto) as voto_max
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(voto_grezzo) as voto, ID_lezione
    FROM risposta_utente
    WHERE ID_corso_sede_utente = 260, risposta_utente.attivo = 1
    GROUP BY ID_lezione
) AS voti 
JOIN lezioni
ON lezioni.ID_lezione=voti.ID_lezione
```

Mysql signal errors on lines 2, 3 and 7 (around the brackets enclosing the subquery). In particular it say:

- expecting expression, "(" found (line 2);
- unexpected token near "(" (line 3);
- unexpected token near ")" (line 7);
- unknown keyword near "AS" (line 7);
- unexpected token near "voti" (line 7);

Comment: `WHERE ID_corso_sede_utente = 260, risposta_utente.attivo = 1` should probably be `WHERE ID_corso_sede_utente = 260 AND risposta_utente.attivo = 1`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: Just curious- how do you know that it's 260?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Where' clause should be separated by "and" and not comma.

```
SELECT titolo, MAX(voto) as voto_max
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(voto_grezzo) as voto, ID_lezione
    FROM risposta_utente
    WHERE ID_corso_sede_utente = 260 **and** risposta_utente.attivo = 1
    GROUP BY ID_lezione
) AS voti 
JOIN lezioni
ON lezioni.ID_lezione=voti.ID_lezione
```

And one more thing, if you are running this is unix mysql console then adding tab will throw an error. Remove the blank spaces before each line and try

```
SELECT titolo, MAX(voto) as voto_max
FROM (
SELECT AVG(voto_grezzo) as voto, ID_lezione
FROM risposta_utente
WHERE ID_corso_sede_utente = 260 **and** risposta_utente.attivo = 1
GROUP BY ID_lezione
) AS voti 
JOIN lezioni
ON lezioni.ID_lezione=voti.ID_lezione
```

Or try executing it as a single line.

Comment: The problem was the AND. Anyhow thanks also for the second hint; I've never launched query in unix mysql console, but that's an useful info.

Answer (score 0):

`where` command should be as expression.

either

```
WHERE ID_corso_sede_utente = 260 AND risposta_utente.attivo = 1
```

or

```
WHERE ID_corso_sede_utente = 260 OR risposta_utente.attivo = 1
```

based on your business logic